# HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor, post-processor

When I recorded my requests I add product in cart, I got this path when click on the button **Add to cart**
/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvc2tpbmJlYXV0eS5jb20vZGFpbHktcG93ZXItYy1wbHVz/product/9491/

In code script on-page, I find %25uenc%2, it's dynamic value is generated every time when I add a product to cart. This parameter doesn't display in parameters will the request. How I need to write Pre or Postprocessor to get this value?

/checkout\/cart\/add\/uenc\/%25uenc%25\/product\/9491\/","data":
"url":"https://********/checkout/cart/add/uenc/%25uenc%25/product/9491/"

Comment: I suspect you'll find the "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvc2tpbmJlYXV0eS5jb20vZGFpbHktcG93ZXItYy1wbHVz" value comes from a previous interaction with the site. Use Fiddler, or similar tool, to record the session and then search for the value. Once you've found this then post the response here and we'll work out the post processor required

Comment: Yeah, I have this link on product page in html code. How i need to get this link in my path i request if i need to have server name and path or server name field can be missed? <form data-product-sku="????" action="https://??????????????.???/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvc2tpbmJlYXV0eS5jb20vY2xlYXItc2tpbi1jbGVhbnNlcg%2C%2C/product/9195/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"

Comment: Yeah, I have this link on the product page in HTML code. How do I need to get this link in my path if request I need to have a server name and path or server name field can be missed? <form data-product-sku="????" action="https://??????????????.???/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvc2tpbmJlYXV0eS5jb20vY2xlYXItc2tpbi1jbGVhbnNlcg%2C%2C/product/9195/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" @ratsstack

Comment: use a JMeter "Boundary Extractor" and set left boundary as "uenc/" and right boundary as "%2c". Stick that in a variable e.g. EXTRACTEDVALUE, and excess it anywhere you need using ${EXTRACTEDVALUE}

Comment: @ratstack, could you please help me and show one example how I need to do this? gloskinbeauty.com